# JavaScript: Rewrite line of code to not use eval()

Tags: javascript

I am not an expert when working with JavaScript, I have the  following piece of JavaScript code:

```
var cat='';
cat+='<div><a class="hl">Supplies</a><div class="tb1" id="agriculture-supplies_1" style="display:none">';
if (eval("document.getElementById('supplies')"))
document.getElementById("supplies").innerHTML = cat;
```

I ran it on jsfiddle to tidy it up, and it is recommending to not use eval because it can be harmful.

I would like to ask for help and learn in which other ways I could write the part:

```
if (eval("document.getElementById('supplies')"))
document.getElementById("supplies").innerHTML = cat;
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is wrong with simply `if (document.getElementById('supplies'))`???

Comment: Why does this use `eval` in the first place?

Comment: just remove eval and change it to if(document.getElementById('supplies'))

Comment: I think it is because the code was written a few years ago.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (document.getElementById('supplies'))
```

... will work in any reasonably modern browser. I am not sure why the indirection in the code at which you're looking; perhaps there were very old browsers which didn't have `.getElementById` (but then did they have `.innerHTML`, I wonder?).

EDIT: Just noticed that the same function is used without the `eval` in the next line! You got me. Perhaps this code was tool-generated and the tool generated strange code under certain circumstances.

Comment: I am cleaning some of the JavaScript errors that Firefox is returning. I am not a coder, and that is why I needed to ask to people that know about it. Thank you for the help and explanation.